# Selenium WebDriver ChromeDriver 2.6GB of "Modified Memory" and increasing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, memory, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running C# Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v84.0.4147.3001 from .Net Core 3.1 WEB APPLICATION and Windows "MODIFIED MEMORY" do not stop increasing. When chromedriver.exe process reached 2.6 GB of Modified Memory other processes started crashing (full computer memory usage). "Regular" memory usage is OK, around 200 MB for chromedriver.

For chrome.exe was created 5 instances and memory usage was around 100 MB and 500 MB of modified memory total.

I'm running it in a Windows Server 2019 16gb + 8gb pagefile.
These are the ChromeDriver startup options:

--disable-gpu, --width=1920, --height=1080, --mute-audio, --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-breakpad

I tried with and without "--headless" mode. Normal mode is lighter.

I need to run multiple instances of chromewebdriver, but that way is impossible. Looks like Memory Leak, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: sounds like you should report that to google and stop using the beta.

Comment: @TatianaPerere Added another dup target incase that helps you anyway.